# How to update key value in talend with tmysqloutput component

Tags: mysql, talend, talend-mdm

My scenario is like, I have the `tMysqlOutput` component is like as follows

`tMysqlOutput` ---> Basic settings ---> `Action on table` is **Default**  and `Action on Data` is **Update**

`tMysqlOutput` ---> Advanced settings -----> Use field options

[image]

I want to update indicator (indicator is key column also), but i am unable to update the indicator

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: What does `but i am unable to update the indicator` mean? Do you get an error message? Anything else?

Comment: In that image the column name

Comment: I didn't understand that comment. How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: Actually indicator is column name in the table (you can observe in the image), it is updatable and key column also. In the output  what i got i.e in the table after running the job, I observed that indicator column not updated

Answer (score 2):

Can you please confirm, Have you committed the transaction after updating the table.
Please use tMysqlCommit after output comoponent or select "Auto Commit" in tmysqlConnection comoponent.
**tmysqlConnection --> Advanced settings.**

Comment: thanks for your answer......I already done the above settings but still i am unable to do my operations

Answer (score 1):

When updating a field value, Talend/MySQL needs a primary key field to find the correct record.

Since it is looking up the field with the primary key, it might not be possible to update the very field which has been used for looking up the row.

You might be able to achieve what you want with an additional autoincrementing `id` field.

This `id` field would be the `Update Key` and nothing else is selected. Then `indicator` would be `Updateable`.

[Source](https://www.rilhia.com/tutorials/using-auto-generated-primary-key-update-row-just-inserted-mysql-database)

Comment: thanks tobi6 for answering the question ......but in my case indicator column itself is a update key

Comment: What about the idea adding an `id` autoincrement field?